# Counting string list in lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists:

```
bigList = [["A1.1", "A2.1", "A3.1", "A4.1"], ["A3.1", "A4.1", "A5.1"], ["A4.1", "A5.1"]] 
smallList = ["A4.1", "A5.1"]
```

What is the fastest way in Python to count how many times `bigList` (lists) contain `smallList`.

At the moment, the right answer is 2.
Maybe I should use Numpy array?

Comment: you cant go faster than O(n) i believe

Comment: `["A3.1", "A4.1", "A5.1"]` isn't an exact match but if you are looking to see if sublists contain the same elements as `smallList` the complexity increases

Comment: @JohnSmith I realize it contains the same elements but you can't use `==` or `in` which then increases complexity

Answer (score 1):

You can use set method `issubset`:

[image]

> Syntax:

```
A.issubset(B)
```

**Return Value from issubset()**

> The issubset() returns

```
True if A is a subset of B
False if A is not a subset of B

bigList = [["A1.1", "A2.1", "A3.1", "A4.1"], ["A3.1", "A4.1", "A5.1"], ["A4.1", "A5.1"]]
smallList = ["A4.1", "A5.1"]

count={}

track=1
for sub_list in bigList:
    if set(smallList).issubset(sub_list):
        if tuple(smallList) not in count:
            count[tuple(smallList)]=track
        else:
            count[tuple(smallList)]+=1

print(count)
```

> output:

```
{('A4.1', 'A5.1'): 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a list contains another list entirely, we can use a set comparison:

`set(smallerList) <= set(biggerList)`

This returns `True` if all elements of `smallerList` are contained in the set of `biggerList`. Do note that this method checks if the individual items are contained and not the order - which sets do not regard. As such it cannot be used if the sequence order matters.

From here we can use a simple list comprehension to check through all the sets of `bigList` and apply the above check. Then we just `sum` up the number of sets that did contain the smaller set (aka we add 1 if it is a match, 0 if not).

`count = sum([1 if set(smallList) <= set(bigList) else 0 for x in bigList])`

As pointed out by **N. Ivanov** - this will scale linearly depending on how many sublists are contained in `bigList`.